# intel xdk project 340 mb size upload to Google Play store size limit 100mb

Tags: android, google-play, apk, intel-xdk

i have made one cross-platform mobile application with Intel xdk but it size is 340 MB but now i cannot upload it to google play store  as it say 100 MB is size limit  for android APK

Comment: give a live example plz

Answer (score 0):

what you need is expension File APK. follow this link https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: link describes alternatives to upload images etc once user opens the app for first time. You need to follow instructions given in the link to create a separate expension file APK. you cannot just migrate existing Intel xdk as it is to Google Play Store due to size restriction of 100 MB

Comment: yes then how can i do it do you have live example how to link the data and main apk file example